# Youtube API - how to remove an event listener?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I read the [Youtube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference), and especially the part about **events**

You can add an event listener, using the player method `addEventListener`

For example :

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert('YT player is now on state code ' + event.data);
}

player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
```

My question is :

- Does anybody know a way to **remove** one of these event listeners from the player ?

Comment: See this bug report https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6951&thanks=6951&ts=1423561436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a removeEventListener() method exposed via the ActionScript 3 embedded player. You could always just turn the registered callback into a no-op, like so:

```
window.onPlayerStateChange = function() {};
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Maybe I could also have a look into the raw player object to see if this kind of data can be accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I am adding the event handler as following :

```
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(evt) {
    onPlayerStateChange(evt);
});
```

Then declare some functions :

```
function state_handler1(evt) {
   /* do something */
}   

function state_handler2(evt) {
   /* do something else */
}

// Assign onPlayerStateChange to one of the functions
// (can be switched over later)
var onPlayerStateChange = state_handler1;
```